# Verifying Firebase ID Token in Elixir/Erlang

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I've set up Firebase for frontend authentication and I am sending the ID token, which is a JWT, to my phoenix backend.

I am now stuck trying to verify the JWT.

Google instructions regarding the matter are [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library). tldr, grab the publicly accessible certificate and use it to verify the JWT signature was signed with the correct private key.

I have this so far

```
def verify(token) do
  {:ok, resp} = HTTPoison.get(@cert_url)
  %{body: body} = resp
  body = Poison.Parser.parse!(body, %{})
  {:ok, header} = Joken.peek_header(token)
  cert = body[header["kid"]]
end
```

I'm lost there. Do I need to convert the public certificate to a public key? How do I create a Joken.Signer with RS256 signing algorithm and the public certificate? I am open to solutions that don't use Joken as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I found the JOSE library :D

To finish up the code…

```
def verify(token) do
  {:ok, resp} = HTTPoison.get(@cert_url)
  %{body: body} = resp
  certs = Poison.Parser.parse!(body, %{})
  {:ok, header} = Joken.peek_header(token)
  jwks = JOSE.JWK.from_firebase(certs)
  jwk = jwks[header["kid"]] |> JOSE.JWK.to_map |> elem(1)
  {true, jose_jwt, _} = JOSE.JWT.verify(jwk, token)
  fields = JOSE.JWT.to_map(jose_jwt) |> elem(1)
  {:ok, fields}
end
```

Elixir code can probably be cleaned up ^_^

Answer (score 4):

Slightly more idiomatic version of @fetching_water's solution, which makes use of more pattern matching and uses Hackney instead of HTTPoison:

```
@cert_url "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"

def verify!(token) do
  {:ok, 200, _headers, ref} = :hackney.get(@cert_url)
  {:ok, body} = :hackney.body(ref)
  {:ok, %{"kid" => kid}} = Joken.peek_header(token)

  {true, %{fields: fields}, _} =
    body
    |> Jason.decode!()
    |> JOSE.JWK.from_firebase()
    |> Map.fetch!(kid)
    |> JOSE.JWT.verify(token)

  fields
end
```